React routers: is there an updated syntax in using react routers if there is how does it work please?
i'm trying to import my router and route from react-router-dom but it doesn't come up
I've tried checking some Youtube tutorials but they all use the same method.
I also noticed that the only ones available in the react-router-dom are hashrouter,createhashrouter but no Routers or route

You need to add code to your post.

If you're using react-router-dom you would do it the following way:
Imports:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

Code:
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainElement/>} />
        <Route path="route-one" element={<ElementOne />} />
        <Route path="route-two" element={<ElementTwo />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>

You obviously need to change the elements to you're own components.
I'd suggest reading the documentation to packages you're using, following YouTube videos is great and helpful, but the documentation should help more.
